# Is there a work around to install Livecode dependencies other than their default locations?

Tags: installation, dependencies, livecode

The instructions I found for setting up dependencies for LiveCode say that you must install the dependencies in their default locations (on the C: drive).

"The Windows build scripts currently don't have any ability to auto-discover tools, so you need to install all of the build dependencies to their default locations."

I can't do this because I don't have enough room on my C: drive, so I installed them to spare drive. When I launch LiveCode Community, I get a blank rectangle on my screen.

Is that why? Is there any workaround that anybody might suggest?

Answer (score 0):

On the main bar. In the Edit menu --> Preferences --> Files & Memory --> User Extension